# Quickly Split CSV line that is Comma Delimited with quotes around Strings in Powerhell

Tags: csv, powershell

I have large CSV files that 0.5-2gb+ files I am trying to import with Powershell.

Data looks like so:

Name, Date, Value

"Joe, John", 2016-08-01, "value"

"Smith, Jane", 2016-08-01, "value"
...

I have this function

```
$elapsed = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($csv)

while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)  {

    # Use RegEx to only split on (,) outside quotes and remove quoted strings            
    $row = ($line -split ',(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)').Replace("`"","")

    # Row Indicator
    $i++; 

    if (($i % 50000) -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "$i rows have been processed in $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())." 
    }
}
```

Splitting the line by a comma "," works perfect as I get ~16K a second, but I need to only split outside of any quotes, so I implemented the regular expression, however the performance tanks to 900 rows a second.

I am looking for a more efficient way to loop through a CSV file that is comma delimited but has commas in the quotes that need to be excluded.

Comment: Why not the built-in `Import-Csv` cmdlet that handles quotes automatically?

Comment: Any kind of regex will kill performance. You need to use simple string operations (if you need speed), but first, the question above this needs addressing.

Comment: Because Import-Csv reads the entire file into memory. I'm attempting to use this with the BulkCopy function and set the batch size to 50K at a time. Unless I'm missing something, Import-CSV doesn't do that.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's a stream reader like yours (I looked at the source) It reads it and pushes it out to a pipeline. If you do something like this `$var = Import-Csv file.csv` then yes, it will read it all into memory. If you pass that into a pipeline (such as ForEach-Object) you can deal with it immediately.

Comment: That you are correct sir. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import-Csv, as noted in the comments above, does not load everything into memory unless you ask it to. Like the example in the question it implements a stream reader and pushes the content it's read off to the output pipeline.

You will see significant memory usage if you do something like this:

```
$var = Import-Csv thefile.csv
```

After all, the content of the CSV has to go somewhere.

Whereas if you do something with the output pipeline there's less impact. e.g.

```
Import-Csv thefile.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Do-Something
}
```

Finally, Import-Csv really doesn't work for you I have a CSV reader class along with a side-by-side implementation of Import-Csv called [Indented.Text.Csv](https://github.com/indented-automation/Indented.Text.Csv) on github. This implementation provides a public class with a number of features I needed so I could process CSV files very quickly.